# What is a Bamf?

Tags: marvel, x-men

Before you get confused by the title, I am aware that the term bamf is used when Nightcrawler teleports. However, I have recently started reading All-New X-Men: Inevitable, and there is a character there that is referred to as 'a Bamf'. The character is named Pickles, and appears to enjoy eating pizza and drinking beer. So, my question: what is a Bamf, and when were they first introduced?

Comment: http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Bamf_(Race)

Comment: A Bamf is a character who enjoys eating pizza and drinking beer? Looks like I found my new user name!

Comment: @user14111 - It's nice to have a few people like you here [who use their real name](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7377/55866). Please don't change it to something fake.

Comment: @Valorum, ibid, Edlothiad, fez, & Mithrandir-My apologies for the duplicate question; I searched the archives for a similar answer, but must have missed it. My bad!

Comment: "What is a Bamf, and what do you season it with"

Comment: Has not one considered that this is "getting crap past the radar" BAMF  = Bad Ass and you get the rest

Answer (score 6):

### A sound Nightcrawler makes when he teleports and [small imp-like creatures](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Bamf_(Race))

For your question, it is used to describe small, imp-like versions of Nightcrawler that are [native to Earth-5311](http://www.comicbookdb.com/team.php?ID=3317). There first appearance seems to be in Uncanny X-men #153

[image: Bamf]

On Earth-616, in the first Nightcrawler limited series in 1985, Nightcrawler is sent to the same universe as these creatures and encounters the bamf that helped Kitty pride in the original Uncanny X-men #513, and ends up discovering that the females are larger than the males, more alike to himself.

The term bamf originates with the sound Nightcrawler made when he teleported.

[image: Nightcrawler goes Bamf]